# Runtime.getRuntime().exec could not execute/show Tabtip.exe

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I've set this OnClick method in JavaFX SceneBuilder on a text field that will pop up the Windows 8 touch keyboard if the user select the textfield. However it seems to be nothing happen when I click on the textfield but when I try to check Tabtip.exe in the task manager, it did shown up there. The codes are:

```
try

{ 
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRtuntime();
 rt.exec( "cmd /c C:\\Programs Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe");
}


catch 
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is not errors triggered or whatsoever, and TabTip.exe is running in task manager, but the pop up keyboard does not show up, anyone has any solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: 1- Use `ProcessBuilder`, 2- Try `\"C:\\Programs Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe\"` instead - of and `cmd /c` my not like long path names...

Comment: Yep, the file path with spaces in it will need wrapping with quotes.

Comment: I did try putting only "\"C:\\Programs Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe\", but I got runtime error when I click on the textfield saying "java.IOException: CreateProcess error=740. The request operation requires elevation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to execute a command which contains spaces in command prompt, you have to wrap it in double quotes.

Like this:

```
String commandStr = "cmd /c \"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\mip.exe\"";
rt.exec( commandStr );
```

And In addition to that, if you want to know your errors, you can get error stream from object of class Process which is returned by runtimeObject.exec().

```
String commandStr =  "cmd /c C:\\Programs Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe";   // Like you did

InputStream is = rt.exec( commandStr ).getErrorStream();
int b;
while((b=(is.read()))!=-1)
  System.out.print((char)b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! the keyboard now pops up :)

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this. For me it is ok in window10 with javaFx application.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "\"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p;
try
{
    p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true)
    {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)`enter code here`
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run the TabTip.exe is to run the software on Admin mode.

I found the following batch code on the internet.

[How to Use On-Screen and Touch Keyboard Instead of Spiral Keyboard](https://www.riotbits.com/controller-companion-how-to-use-on-screen-and-touch-keyboard-instead-of-spiral-keyboard-14263/)

```
tasklist | find /I "TabTip.exe" >NUL && (taskkill /IM "TabTip.exe" /T)
start "" "TabTip.exe"
```

That code kills the TabTip process and executes a new TabTip.

In my case, I created a file called keyboard.bat and added the previous example.

In java, I created a method in order to read this file in the same folder.

That is my code

```
try{
  File file = new File("keyboard.bat");
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file.getAbsolutePath());
}catch(IOException ex){        
  Logger.getLogger(RunGazePoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

after that, I compile my app and wrap it in executable mode with launch4j software.

Another way Is to execute by command, If you are using a multithreaded the system can avoid the lecture of file and not execute the software.

create two methods in order to kill and call the keyboard.

```
    //hide the Keyboard
            String[] array = new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","taskkill /IM \"TabTip.exe\" /F\n" +
""};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(array);

//Show the keyboard
            String[] array = new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start \"\" \"TabTip.exe\""};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(array);
```